# Ability to generate camel case interface from existing snake case

Tags: typescript

Given I have an interface that uses snake case for keys:

```
interface helloUnderscore {
  hello_world: boolean
}
```

Is it possible to create a `Camel` type that loops over the input interface?

```
type hello = Camel<hello>;
```

And creates a type that has all the keys in camel case?

```
const hi: hello = {
   helloWorld: true // valid
}
```

Comment: Not posiible in TS currently.

Comment: Ok, thank you! This is great to know.